# What Is This Diagonalizable Matrix Doing to Its EigenVector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$.  It is diagonalizable with:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}$$

We may say that $A$ doesn't do anything on $(1, -1)^t$ but elongates $(1, 2)^t$ by $4$.  Now stack the eigenvectors into a matrix called $X$ and we'll have $AX = XD$:

$$\begin{align} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \ \ & = \ \ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \ \ & = \ \ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2/3 & -1/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}$$

Now, I'm going to feed $(1, -1)^t$ into the last equation.  On the left-hand side, as stated before, $A$ will do nothing to it.  But what is happening on the right-hand side?  For example, in the first multiplication, we'll have:

$$\begin{align} \begin{bmatrix} 2/3 & -1/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \ \ & = \ \ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \end{align}$$

I'm aware that $X^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 2/3 & -1/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3\end{bmatrix}$ is a change of coordinate matrix.  So it takes $(1, -1)^t$, the coordinates corresponding to the standard basis into $(1, 0)^t$ the coordinates corresponding to the eigenbasis.  But what is happening in the second step?

$$\begin{align} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \ \ = \ \ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \end{align}$$

Comment: I don't undertstand the question, since you seem to have answered it in the last equation. This computation illustrates the general procedure: the inverse of the change-of-basis matrix sends an eigenvalue to a standard basis vector, the diagonal matrix simply scales that standard basis vector, and then the change-of-basis matrix finally sends that multiple of the standard basis vector back to a multiple of the original eigenvalue.

Comment: @GregMartin, I think this is why I didn't understand it.  The $(1, 0)^t$ in the last equation is not the usual $e_1$.  Rather it is the coordinates of $(1, -1)^t$ in terms of the eigenvectors.

Comment: It's both at the same time! :D This is the magic of the change-of-basis matrix—it literally changes one basis into another basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second step $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ scales $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ by the eigenvalue $1$, resulting a scaled standard vector to "select" one eigenvector column from $X$.

Trying with the other eigenvector $XDX^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ may be clearer.